# Does this sentence make sense?

Tags: translation, particle-は, particle-が

Does this sentence make sense?

> 山本さんは水曜日の食事**が**体に悪いと思います。

It's supposed to mean:

> I think Yamamoto's Wednesday meal was unhealthy (lit. bad for the body)

I'm particularly unsure about my use of the particle が.

Comment: Yamamoto's Wednesday meal is 山本さんの水曜日の食事.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think Yamamoto's Wednesday meal was unhealthy.

If this is what you want to say, I think you can say:

> - 山本さんの水曜日の食事**は**、体に悪かったと思います。/ 体に良くなかったと思います。
>     lit. "I think Yamamoto-san's Wednesday meal was bad for health. / not good for health."
>     (more literal to "I think Yamamoto's Wednesday meal was unhealthy.")
>     OR
> - 山本さんは、水曜日の食事**が**体に悪かったんだと思います。/ 体に良くなかったんだと思います。
>     lit. "As for Yamamoto-san, I think his Wednesday meal was bad for health. / not good for health."
>     (which is closer to "As for Yamamoto-san, I think the problem was his Wednesday meal." / "I think Yamamoto-san's problem is that his Wednesday meal was unhealthy.")

---

Your sentence:

> 山本さんは水曜日の食事が体に悪いと思います。

sounds a bit unnatural... You could instead say:

> 山本さんは水曜日の食事が体に悪いと思**っています**。

to mean "Yamamoto-san thinks that (every) Wednesday meal is unhealthy", or

> 山本さんは水曜日の食事が体に悪**かった**と思**っています**。

to mean "Yamamoto-san thinks that his Wednesday meal **was** unhealthy."

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit unsure towards whom this line is supposed to be addressed. I'm answering this based on the assumption that you are not talking to 山本

> 山本さんは水曜日の食事が体に悪いと思います。

I think this means "Yamamoto-san thinks [someone's] Wednesday's meal was bad for [someone's health]."

I'd make the following changes:

1. 山本さんは → 山本さんの
2. 食事が → 食事は (mostly because of the previous change)
3. 体に悪い → 体に悪そう
4. 思います is no longer needed after the 悪い → 悪そう change.

I ended up with:

> 山本さんの水曜日の食事は体に悪そうでした。
>
> Yamamoto's Wednesday meal looked unhealthy.

If you were talking to 山本 directly, it probably sounds more natural if you have ending particles such as よ or ね (or both).

Comment: "Yamamoto-san thinks ..." translates to 山本さんは…と思っている.

Answer (score 1):

If you suppose a 山本 who is unhealthy is asking the doctor what's wrong with him, and the doctor replies as it's his Wednesday meal that does harm, 山本さんは水曜日の食事がからだに悪い**のだ**と思います works and it's natural.